# How to retain technical information about new features?

Tags: self-learning

I'm going through an online training on Apex and Salesforce (trailhead), and I don't know how to retain all this info. I'm memorizing it, and trying to build stuff, but I'm still not retaining it.... Does anyone have any recommendations on how to retain all this info?

Ex - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_triggers/units/apex_triggers_intro

I know that this isn't the right channel for this question, but I couldn't find a more suitable one. If the mods want to close this, I ask that you point me in the direction of the right channel (I've posted this on Reddit too, without much success).

Comment: seems relevant to me. It is about teaching or learning. It is about computer science, IT, or digital literacy. ☺

Comment: Is this the first such system you have tried to learn? The first one is going to be gobbledygook, the 2nd one will be a bit familiar, the 3rd will totally make sense and then you can learn any similar system. Same with languages. Same with mathematics, same with... everything. Try learning a different system, then compare and contrast. Find the essential unity behind them, the intention.

Answer (score 3):

"Memorizing" doesn't do much to help you retain information or build skills. In order to really remember it you have to move it from short term memory, where it is pretty volatile to long term memory. The trick for doing this is to practice it. The reason teachers give students lots of exercises is to help them with this process.

In order to learn anything, the brain needs to be physically changed, connecting neurons with synapses in a new way. This is only done with repetition and practice.

See The Art of Changing the Brain by James E Zull  for a run-down on the science behind it.

Do, if the course provides exercises do them all. If you have a book available that also has exercises on the material, do  those as well.

Comment: Practicing with exercises will work just fine (see anybody who is learning to play a musical instrument), but from a motivational perspective I would additionally recommend to immediately try to apply the newly gained knowledge to a relevant problem one actually wants (or at least: needs) to solve.

Answer (score 2):

With complex dynamic systems like SalesForce, you will never be able to remember everything. What is more important than memorizing is that you learn the SME language and how to find the answers in the documentation as you need them.

Google is the consultant's best friend.